# Some confusions about css overflow

Tags: css, overflow

Recently I am learning some stuff about CSS,I found some awesome tricks about `overflow`:

1. Set parents of float elements to `overflow:hidden` or `overflow:auto` can keep parents from collapsing

   ```
   <div style="overflow: auto;">
       <div style="float: left;">Div 1</div>
       <div style="float: left;">Div 2</div>        
   </div>
   ```
2. make two columns have same height,set a big enough padding at the `bottom`of each floated element, and countering it with an equal negative `margin` at the bottom of the same elements. The trick is to set the `overflow` on the parent container to hidden

I can not image how it work,why is `overflow` so obscure? someone can explain it?

Comment: overflow:auto; only makes sense when it's height is restricted with height:somepixels or ems or whatever; then you get a scroll bar so you can still see all of the content by scrolling.

Comment: While 1 is something of a side-effect of being necessary so that the browser can implement non-visible overflow in some sane way, 2 is just what hidden overflow does. There's nothing obscure about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The clearfix behavior you describe in 1 is a well known properties of `overflow` as you can see here: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/overflow/#article-header-id-6 and http://www.stubbornella.org/content/2009/07/23/overflow-a-secret-benefit/ and this is an expected behavior, since it is part of the CSS 2.1 spec: https://www.w3.org/TR/2004/CR-CSS21-20040225/visudet.html#root-height (see the last sentence of the 10.6.7 'Auto' heights for block formatting context roots paragraph)

The 2 is (as @alohci says in the comment) the `overflow: hidden` expected behavior.

For further details you can read the official spec: https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visufx.html#overflow